# Join 2 tables VB.NET

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I got this code:

```
strSQL += " ,allow_grp_desc as PayAlwGroup, deduct_grp_desc as PayDedGroup, unit_rate_grp_desc as PayUnitRateGroup, Ot_grp_name as OTGrpName
```

This will generate a report with different column respectively. All column field are in same table(employee table). So I want to add new column name "is_prorate" in the report but it belongs to different table called "employee_salary". Can some suggest me how to insert the coding because I already try many solution but it don't work.

Example:

```
strSQL += " SELECT CASE is_basic_prorate WHEN '1' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' as BasicProrate from employee_salary_setup WHERE Company_id = '" & gstrCompanyId & "' ,"
```

Error message:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'INNER'. Incorrect syntax near the
>   keyword 'as'.

Expected output:

```
PayAlwGroup PayDedGroup PayUnitRateGroup    OTGrpName        BasicProrate
STANDARD    STANDARD    STANDARD            NO OVERTIME          Y
```

Comment: It's called an "inner join".  You should look it up.

Comment: You need to provide data in the form as provided in the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53756725/what-would-be-the-query-for-employee-who-work-for-all-the-department/53760299#53760299

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer finally. Let me share you my solution.

```
strSQL += " ,allow_grp_desc as PayAlwGroup, deduct_grp_desc as PayDedGroup, unit_rate_grp_desc as PayUnitRateGroup, Ot_grp_name as OTGrpName, employee_salary_setup.CASE is_basic_prorate WHEN '1' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' as BasicProrate

strSQL += " from employee LEFT OUTER JOIN employee_salary_setup ON employee.emp_id = employee_salary_setup.emp_id"
```

The result is same as expected output in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend your query as shown below

```
strSQL += " SELECT is_prorate, CASE is_basic_prorate WHEN '1' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' as BasicProrate from employee_salary_setup inner join employee_salary on employee_salary_setup.EmpId = employee_salary.EmpId  WHERE Company_id = '" & gstrCompanyId & "' ,"
```

To know more about join in sql server you can learn [SQL Server Joins](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

Comment: Hi Suraj. Thank for your help. Already try using your code but doesn't work.

Comment: Can you provide employee_salary_setup and employee_salary table structure with some sample data.